# HTTP POST in Espruino for Microcontrollers

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I recently got myself an esp8266-12e module and loaded the ESPRUINO.js firmware on it. I am trying execute a post request from the device, but the device always returns a 'no connection' error when trying to POST.

To troubleshoot I have ran a GET request to the same URL, and the request was successful, this means that internet is working on the device and communication with the intended server is possible.

I then moved on to see if there were errors in my HTTP POST code, I ran the same code in a node.js app and it successfully posted to the server.

Here is the code below, I removed the exact address of my server and my wifi/pass info.

```
var http = require("http");
var wifi = require("Wifi");

var sdata = {
 deviceID: 'esp-12',
};

var options = {
  hostname: 'immense-XXXXXX-XXXXX.herokuapp.com',
  method: 'POST',
  path:'/MXXXXXX',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(body) {
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
  });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
payload = JSON.stringify(sdata);
req.write(payload);
req.end();
```

terminal response from device after execution

```
problem with request: no connection
```

Here is the documentation for Espruino.js HTTP module. 
https://www.espruino.com/Reference#http

Can any of the JS gurus see an issue with the request?

Comment: You're wrapping the HTTP-related code with `wifi.connect()`?

Comment: I have the wifi config saved onto the device using `wifi.save()`, Should I make the request a callback to `wifi.connect`?

Comment: From the documentation (I'm not very familiar with Espruino), it seems that having called `wifi.save()` should be enough for the firmware to re-connect to the saved WiFi network at startup (although there's also a `wifi.restore()` which seems to do the same...). However, given the error you're getting you might try and see if using an explicit `wifi.connect()` solves your problem nonetheless. Also, read the last item here: https://www.espruino.com/ESP8266_WifiUsage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the http post request requires the `'content-length'` header to function correctly.

Here is the working post request model for anyone who may need it. Note: Payload has already been formatted as a JSON object.

```
function postX(payload) {
var options = {
  host: 'url',
  port: '80',
  path:'/ext',
  method:'POST',
  headers: { "Content-Type":"application/json", "Content-Length":payload.length }
};
var req = require("http").request(options, function(res)  {
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("-->"+data);
  });
  res.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log("==> Closed.");
    ticksSinceConnect = 0;
  });
 });
req.end(payload);}
```